# $3 \tan^{-1 }(x-2) +\pi =0$

Tags: trigonometry

Please help. I don't know where to start.
Do I use the addition rule, or do I start with the double angle formula? I've never done one with the pie sign before!!

It should be $3\tan^{-1} (x-2) + \pi = 0$

Comment: I assume you mean cotangent, not inverse tan?

Comment: Please make sure I got the formatting right.  @OliverBel:  I think it is $\arctan$

Comment: The addition rule (aka sum of angles rule) and the double angle formula apply to the $\tan$ function, not the $\tan^{-1}$ (aka arctan) function. Also note that $\tan(\tan^{-1}(x-2)) = x-2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Subtract $\pi$ from each side
Divide by 3
Take the tangent

Can you go from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\pi$ is just a number.  We get after algebra that $x = 2+ \tan({-\frac{\pi}{3}})$

Answer (score 0):

You should treat equation like any other equation. Remember, you have to isolate for $x$. So the first thing you would do is move the $\pi$ over to left side like you would with any other number, *remember* it is a number and not a variable. So you would have something like this:

$$3\tan^{-1} (x-2) = -\pi$$

Now, you have a $3$ and a $\tan^{-1}$ you need to get rid of. So the first thing you will do is divide by three right? Then you're going to take the $\tan$ from there because that is the opposite of $\tan^{-1}$. So let's recap what we've done here:

1. Move $\pi$ over to the right side
2. Then divide by $3$ because that's opposite of multiplication
3. Then take the $\tan$ of both sides because that is the opposite of $\tan^{-1}$.

From step three on, if you have done everything right then you should have $x-2$ on the left side with other stuff on the right. If you need any help, be sure to comment.